# Como puedo convertir un Array boolean a un Array int

Tags: javascript

Tengo los siguientes arreglos:

```
Array = [false, true, false, true];
```

Pero la quiero convertir a

```
Array2 = [0, 1, 0, 1];
```

Comment: por favor explicate mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listo aquí tienes tu respuesta con un ciclo forEach

```js
const arreglo1 = [true,false,true]
const arreglo2 = []

arreglo1.forEach(function(index, value){
  if(index === true){
arreglo2.push(1)
  }else{
arreglo2.push(0)
  }
})

console.log(arreglo2)
```

> Revisa como es que declaro un arreglo con los valores en formato de
>   número y posterior un arreglo vacío que se va a llenar con el
>   equivalente de esos valores pero en formato booleano

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Te dejo el mismo ejercicio pero hecho con el método map

```js
const arreglo1 = [true,false,true]
const arreglo2 = []

arreglo1.map((index) => {
  if(index === true){
arreglo2.push(1)
  }else{
arreglo2.push(0)
  }
})

console.log(arreglo2)
```

Comment: Perfecto Gracias!

Comment: de nada que bueno te sirvió

Comment: Con `map` no necesitas pasar a mano a otro array los items, ya que de por sí construye un nuevo array con lo que tu devuelvas en la función.

Answer (score 2):

Propongo esta solucion:

```
let array1 = [false, true, false, true]
let array2 = array1.map(e => Number(e)) // [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es que a cada elemento de `array1` le aplico la funcion `Number()`. Esta función convierte el valor ingresado a un numero que represente ese valor. En este caso `True` seria `1` y `false` seria `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.map((e) => {

    if (e) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

});
```

Ten en cuenta que map retorna una nueva array, así que para usarla, debes usarla como una expresión, o guardarla en una nueva variable. Es decir:

```
const Array2 = Array.map((e) => {

    if (e) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

});
```

Comment: tu sintáxis esta incorrecta en Array.map además el OP pide convertir por ejemplo un true a un 1, cosa que no muestra la respuesta

Comment: Corregido lo que espera el OP, lo había hecho al contrario. Pero la sintáxis no está incorrecta. Solo parece que estoy accediendo al método desde el Array.prototype.map, pero simplemente así llamo el OP a la variable, Array.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el método `map` que tienen todos los array desde ES5. No necesitas crear un nuevo array ni estarle haciendo push.

```
var Array2 = [false, true, false, true].map(function (item) { 
    return item ? 1 : 0
})

console.log(Array2) // [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

O con ES6 es aún más legible:

```
var Array2 = [false, true, false, true].map(item => item ? 1 : 0)

console.log(Array2) // [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas!

Lo que se me ocurre es: con tu `Array1`, después haces un bucle for con sus valores. Dentro de ese bucle haces un if en el que si `Array1[0]=false`, hacer un `push()` al `Array2` con valor 0 y al revés con el `true`.

No sé si me he explicado bien, pero la idea creo que es buena y fácil de hacer, espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Esa respuesta ya la dieron en código antes. Saludos.